# How to add conditional rows which consist of few user inputs in Shiny app

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny

I would like to show in UI only the first row (currently `fluidRow`) with device, color and linetype if user chooses number one, two first rows if user chooses number two and so on.

How do I add this kind of condition. I tried `conditionalPanel` but I failed there.

Tried to make a minimal reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(2, offset = 1,
             selectInput(inputId = "number",
                         label = "Number:",
                         choices = list(
                           "One data set" = "1",
                           "Two data sets" = "2",
                           "Three data sets" = "3"))
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(2,
             selectInput(inputId = "dev1",
                         label = "Device:",
                         choices = list("Device 1", "Device 2"))
      ),
      column(2,
             selectInput(inputId = "col1",
                         label = "Color:",
                         choices = list("black", "red", "blue"))

      ),
      column(2,
             selectInput(inputId = "lty1",
                         label = "Linetype:",
                         choices = list("solid", "dashed"))
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(2,
             selectInput(inputId = "dev2",
                         label = "Device:",
                         choices = list("Device 1", "Device 2"))
      ),
      column(2,
             selectInput(inputId = "col2",
                         label = "Color:",
                         choices = list("black", "red", "blue"))

      ),
      column(2,
             selectInput(inputId = "lty3",
                         label = "Linetype:",
                         choices = list("solid", "dashed"))
      )
    )
  ),
  server <- function(input, output) {})
```

Tell me if this needs more clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution using server side logic, client side (JS) is also an option however this seems more natural given the platform in R and also it offers more control.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(2, offset = 1,
             selectInput(inputId = "number",
                         label = "Number:",
                         choices = list(
                           "One data set" = "1",
                           "Two data sets" = "2",
                           "Three data sets" = "3"))
      )
    ),
    uiOutput('dynamic_selections')
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$number,{
      output$dynamic_selections = renderUI({
        lapply(1:as.integer(input$number),function(i){
          fluidRow(
            column(2,
                   selectInput(inputId = sprintf("dev%s",i),
                               label = "Device:",
                               choices = list("Device 1", "Device 2"))
            ),
            column(2,
                   selectInput(inputId = sprintf("col%s",i),
                               label = "Color:",
                               choices = list("black", "red", "blue"))

            ),
            column(2,
                   selectInput(inputId = sprintf("lty%s",i),
                               label = "Linetype:",
                               choices = list("solid", "dashed"))
            ),
            column(2,
                   shinyFilesButton(id=sprintf("file%s",i), label='File:',title = 'Select File',multiple=FALSE, buttonType = "default", class = NULL)
            )
          )
        })
      })
      lapply(1:as.integer(input$number),function(i){
        shinyFileChoose(input, sprintf("file%s",i), roots=c(wd='.'), filetypes=c('', 'txt'))
      })
    })
  })
```

EDIT: it has been highlighted that in some scenarios the file chooser box is not populated. Two things could go wrong

1. JS cannot read date attribute of folder/file therefore array is populated with null and errors when trying string split:

   > var mTime = data.files.mtime[i].split('-')

   as a temp solution this can be avoided using restrictions parameter to exclude problematic folders/files?
2. When shinyFilesButton() is rendered via renderUI and server logic then fileChooser fails to populate but without any JS error, needs to be investigated further

Comment: Works like a charm but can't get this to work with shinyFilesButton and shinyFilesChoose if I have them as a mean to select a path to file as an extra column with the device, color and linetype choices.

Comment: changed code to accept files button and server logic for it

Comment: Any clue why it doesn't show any folders/files when you click to choose a file? At least for me it isn't showing any even though I tried changing the roots. Otherwise superb again!

Comment: made a mistake, lapply should have only one shinyFileChoose contructor, fixed. Sorry i am not familiar with shinyFiles never used this before. I have added my findings into the main answer here, i will check further later today, if there is no solution using R then i will write you a javascript solution for the excercise

Comment: Yeah I figured those two additional shinyFileChoose shouldn't be there. Haven't been able to make this solution work with what I want (shinyFilesButton and shinyFileChoose) but I used it in another situation just fine (a situation which corrensponds to the original problem).